# Generics in Sequence Extensions

Tags: arrays, swift, generics, closures

I have some code which I'm trying to make generic, and can't quite figure out how.

```
func randomInt() -> Int { return Int(arc4random_uniform(42)) }

let closures = [randomInt, randomInt, randomInt, randomInt]

let result = closures.map { $0() }
print(result)
```

In essence, I want to take an array of closures, that return some value of type `T`, and return an array of type `[T]` with all the results.

This is my attempt:

```
extension Sequence where Element == () -> T
{
    func callAll() -> [T]
    {
        return self.map { $0() }
    }
}
```

However, this clearly doesn't work, as `T` is undefined. How would I go about writing this extension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the generic `callAll` function work only on `Sequence`s, where `Element` is of type `()->T`, but as far as I know, you cannot declare a generic type in a where clause to an extension.

```
extension Sequence {
    func callAll<T>() -> [T] where Self.Element == ()->T{
        return self.map { $0() }
    }
}

func randomInt() -> Int { return Int(arc4random_uniform(42)) }

let closures = [randomInt, randomInt, randomInt, randomInt]

let result = closures.callAll()
print(result) //one sample output: [41, 19, 15, 36]
```